# In the forms of an inline formset can I customize the field generated by can_delete?

Tags: django, django-forms

In the forms of an inline formset can I customize the field generated by can_delete ?

I want to add a class and an attribute to the field, for front-end manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated Solution

```
## forms.py
from django import forms
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory

...
...

class UserForm(forms.Form):
    sso_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'pattern':'[a-z][a-z.]*[a-z]','required':'required'}))
    role = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=[(x,x) for x in ['Admin','Employee']])

UserFormset = formset_factory(UserForm,extra=0,can_delete=True)

...
...
```

```
## views.py
from .forms import UserFormset
...
...
initial_data = [
    {'sso_id':'admin.admin','role':'Admin'},
    {'sso_id':'employee.employee','role':'Employee'},
    {'sso_id':'employee.employeee','role':'Employee'},]

my_formset = UserFormset(initial=initial_data)
for form,data in zip(my_formset,initial_data):
    if data.get('role',None) == 'Admin':
        form.fields['DELETE'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'Admin'
        form.fields['DELETE'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = False
    else:
        form.fields['DELETE'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'Employee'
        form.fields['DELETE'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
...
```

[image]

Comment: where you do this change in __init__ ?, can you extend the example